# How to convert .app file to .ipa file?

Tags: ios, ipa

My client needs me to build the ios app from gaire21.com i have made that app from that platform, after making the app, i requested the binary from that platform, and they returned me .app file, now i need to upload that file on app store, What i am trying to do is, i have made a folder with extension .ipa with app name and i placed the .app file in payload folder something like this
APPNAME.ipa>payload>appname.app but i am facing some issues through this process[image]

where when i validate the app through that platform it returns me green signal, and i have validated with valid provisioning profiles, but now i am facing these problems, please guide me how can i solve this or any appropriate process to validate the .app and convert it into .ipa file? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed the plist file after having the .app from your 'that'

platform. so do not modify or change it after you have it processed from

any 'platform', you just need to follow the hierarchy for compressing the

.app file into .ipa. which you have mentioned in your own post, place your

app within Payload folder and compress it and change the name whatever you

want to make it it doesn't matter. try it and let me know if it will work.

Comment: yeah i have changed the plist after that, thanks it solved my issue.

Comment: yup, just read the logs and try to find out by your own first!